# Tamanho da div com scrollbar em menu

Tags: html, css

```css
.sidebar {
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 11 !important;
}



.sidebar .user-info .info-container .user-helper-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: -3px;
    bottom: -10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}

.sidebar .menu {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 400px;
}

.sidebar .menu .list {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.sidebar .menu .list li.active > :first-child span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .header {
    background: #eee;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}

.sidebar .menu .list i.material-icons {
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.sidebar .menu-toggle {
    color: white;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .menu-toggle:after, .sidebar .menu .list .menu-toggle:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 14px);
    right: 17px;
    font-size: 19px;
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .menu-toggle:before {
    content: '+';
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.sidebar .menu .list .menu-toggle:after {
    content: '\2013';
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}

.sidebar .menu .list .menu-toggle.toggled:before {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}

.sidebar .menu .list .menu-toggle.toggled:after {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.sidebar .menu .list a {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.sidebar .menu .list a:hover {
    background-color: #00b69d;
}

.sidebar .menu .list a small {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 7.5px);
    right: 15px;
}

.sidebar .menu .list a span {
    margin: 7px 0 7px 12px;
    color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .ml-menu {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .ml-menu span {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 3px 0 1px 6px;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .ml-menu li a {
    padding-left: 55px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .ml-menu li.active a.toggled:not(.menu-toggle) {
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .ml-menu li.active a.toggled:not(.menu-toggle):before {
    content: '\E315';
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    position: relative;
    font-size: 21px;
    height: 20px;
    top: -5px;
    right: 0px;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .ml-menu li .ml-menu li a {
    padding-left: 80px;
}

.sidebar .menu .list .ml-menu li .ml-menu .ml-menu li a {
    padding-left: 95px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <!-- Barra lateral -->
    <div id="barralateral" class="sidebar">

        <!-- User Info -->
        <div class="user-info row" align="center">
            <div class="image">
                {% if user_foto_sidebar %}
                <a href="{% url 'login:perfilview' %}"><img src="/media/{{user_foto_sidebar}}" alt="User"
                                                            class="centraliza-imagem"/></a>
                {%else%}
                <a href="{% url 'login:perfilview' %}"><img src="/media/imagens/user.png" alt="User"
                                                            class="centraliza-imagem"/></a>
                {%endif%}
            </div>
            <div class="info-container">
                <div class="name" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

                </div>
                {% if user_empresa %}
                <div class="email">{{user_empresa}}</div>
                {% endif %}
                <!--<div class="email">{{request.user.email}}</div>-->

                <div class="user-helper-dropdown">
                    <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="true">&#xE313;</i>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'login:perfilview' %}"><i class="material-icons">&#xE55A;</i>Perfil</a></li>
                        <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a {% if user_empresa %} href="{% url 'cadastro:editarempresaview' user_empresa.id %}"
                               {%else%} class="popup" title="Selecionar Empresa"
                               href="{% url 'login:selecionarempresaview' %}" {%endif%}><i class="material-icons">&#xE0AF;</i>Minha
                            Empresa</a></li>
                        <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="{% url 'login:usuariosview' %}"><i class="material-icons">&#xE7FB;</i>Usuários</a>
                        </li>
                        <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a id="logout-btn" href="{% url 'login:logoutview' %}" title="Sair"><i
                                class="material-icons">&#xE879;</i>Sair</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- #User Info -->

        <!-- Menu -->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="{% url 'base:index' %}">
                        <span>Página Inicial</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle"
                        <span>Cadastro</span>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
                        <span>Vendas</span>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
                        <span>Compras</span>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
                        <span>Boletos</span>
                    </a>

                </li>


                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
                        <i class="material-icons">&#xE8B0;</i>
                        <span>Fiscal</span>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
                        <i class="material-icons">&#xE227;</i>
                        <span>Financeiro</span>
                    </a>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
                        <i class="material-icons">&#xE1BD;</i>
                        <span>Estoque</span>
                    </a>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'agenda:agendaview' %}">
                        <i class="material-icons">&#xE878;</i>
                        <span>Agenda</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</section>
```

Tenho uma div para um menu lateral, nesse menu existem várias opções, essas opções possuem sub-opções. Para rolar as opções editei da seguinte maneira no css:

```
.sidebar .menu {
position: relative;
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 450px;
}
```

Porém não está responsivo. Em telas maiores o menu fica com espaço sobrando, e em telas menores o menu fica cortado, não aparecendo todas as opções, mesmo rolando a barra.

Já tentei colocar `height: 100%;`, mas a div fica com tamanho maior que a tela, ao fazer a rolagem algumas opções não aparecem.

Como faço para deixar esse menu responsivo?

A execução do código aqui na pergunta ficou um pouco zoada porque uso Python e Django e não consigo inserir toda a informação aqui. Mas dá pra ter uma noção do que está acontecendo.

Comment: Cara primeiramente coloca o código completo ai para a gente poder tentar simular o seu problema. Edita sua pergunta e coloca o HTML e o CSS referente a esse menu ai, sim isso não da para te dar uma resposta precisa....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara fiz esse modelo que pode te ajudar. Mas explicando seu problema é que vc está tentando usar `scroll` em um pai que está com `position:fixed`. Para controlar melhor isso vc vai precisar coloca alguns valores de altura, como no *user-info*, e depois fazer o `calc` para subtrair da altura do menu, tb precisa considerar a altura do `header`, que vc tinha definido como `70px`. Então o `calc` ficaria algo como. `height: calc(100% - 70px - 100px);` par o menu fazer o scroll do jeito correto.

Então como vc pode ver vc tem 2 valores de altura fixos, o header 70px e o user info 100px. De qq forma isso só vai te atrapalha caso a tela do usuário tenha menos que uns 200px de altura, algo bem pouco provável... Assim posso usar overflow:auto, e o scroll só vai aparecer se o conteúdo do filho for maior que a altura do pai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Essa é uma estrutura baseada no seu código ela é mais simples, apenas para fins didáticos, mas acho que vai te ajudar a entender o conceito do layout, e se quiser adaptar seu layout para usar essa estrutura fique a vontade.

Segue o código referente a imagem acima

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    height: 70px;
}
main {
    display: flex;
}
.dados {
    margin-left: 250px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}
aside {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100px;
}
nav {
    height: calc(100% - 70px - 100px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<header>
    header
</header>
<main>
    <section class="menu">
        <aside>
            user info
        </aside>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">item 4</a></li>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit minima in repellendus autem eligendi vitae, aspernatur animi consequuntur excepturi accusamus assumenda, iure facilis saepe accusantium tempore sapiente voluptatum delectus impedit numquam quia esse error omnis recusandae? Quam officiis, veniam suscipit commodi temporibus officia voluptates! Soluta laudantium exercitationem animi reprehenderit vitae fugiat doloremque, natus temporibus deleniti dignissimos ad placeat. Laboriosam ducimus 
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
    <section class="dados">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure cum vero esse dolor nobis tempore culpa, sequi consequuntur amet dolorum distinctio maxime voluptatem reiciendis necessitatibus nulla nam commodi repellendus exercitationem unde quia pariatur perferendis? Quis enim molestias cumque debitis, rerum repellendus. Saepe architecto eius itaque et consequuntur maxime debitis quidem autem iusto nisi praesentium hic aut temporibus corporis possimus, suscipit reprehenderit, ipsam aspernatur deserunt explicabo facilis ipsa repellendus, veniam vel. Sequi culpa explicabo assumenda ratione repellendus. Deleniti aspernatur repudiandae fugit iusto assumenda, at, eligendi sit totam distinctio ipsam nesciunt obcaecati, accusantium asperiores accusamus. Hic laudantium non voluptatum odit adipisci ullam, laboriosam tenetur. Provident voluptatibus reiciendis, deserunt porro aut, blanditiis corrupti illum assumenda quia fugiat. Consectetur eveniet exercitationem nam, voluptas beatae molestias tempore temporibus cum, quibusdam esse nobis ipsum. Eaque soluta non, cupiditate recusandae illo ex cum et eos, modi voluptatibus reiciendis, deserunt porro aut, blanditiis corrupti illum assumenda quia fugiat. Consectetur eveniet exercitationem nam, voluptas beatae molestias tempore temporibus cum, quibusdam esse nobis ipsum. Eaque soluta non, cupiditate recusandae illo ex cum et eos, modi 
    </section>
</main>
```